# My validating a captcha using JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript

```
    <script>
    function validate2(id)
    {
        var regex = [a-z];
        var ctrl =  document.getElemetnById(id);

        if (regex.test(ctrl.value)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>

    <script>

    function TestCompanyName(txtCompanyName){

        var obj = document.getElementById(txtCompanyName);

        var RegEx = /THE DAMN REGULAR EXPRESSION/

        if(RegEx.test(obj.value)==false)

        {

            alert("Invalid");

        }

    }

    </script>
    </script>
    <script>
    function checklname(input1)
    {
        var pattern=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
        return pattern.test(input1);
    }
    if(!isvalid) {
        alert('Invalid name');
        document.getElementById("input1").value = "";
    }
    }
    </script>
    <script>
    function phonenumber(telno) {
      var phoneno = /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
      if(telno.value.match(phoneno))
          {
        return true;
      }  
      else {  
        alert("message");
        return false;
      }
    }

    </script>

    <script>
    function phonenumber2(mobileno) {
      var phoneno1 = /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
      if(mobileno.value.match(phoneno1))
          {
        return true;
      }  
      else {  
        alert("message");
        return false;
      }
    }

    </script>
        <script>

    function validate() {
        var ta = document.getElementById("ta").value;
        var answer  = document.getElementbyId("answer").value;
        var digit1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit1").innerHTML);
        var digit2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit2").innerHTML);
        var sum = digit1 + digit2;
        if(answer == null || answer == ""){
            alert("please add the number");
            return false;
        }else if(answer != sum){
            alert("you math is wrong");
        }else if(ta == null || ta == ""){
            alert("please fill in  the textarea");
        }else{
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing";
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "";
        }
        }


    function randomNums(){
        var rand_num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1;
        var rand_num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1;
        document.getElementById("digit1").innerHTML = rand_num1;
            document.getElementById("digit2").innerHTML = rand_num2;
    }
    </script








    <script>
    function checkEmail(inputvalue){    
    var pattern=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
             return pattern.test(inputvalue); 
    }
    checkEmail('rte@co') // false
    checkEmail('rte@co.com') // true
    </script>
    <script>
    var address = /^[a-zA-Z0-9-\/] ?([a-zA-Z0-9-\/]|[a-zA-Z0-9-\/] )*[a-zA-Z0-9-\/]$/;
                if ( address.test($.trim($('#address').val())) == false)
                {
                     alert('invalid address ');
                }
            </script>
    <script>
    function IsValidZipCode(zipcode) {
            var isValid = /[\^$%@!#&\*:<>\?\/\\~\{\}\(\)\+|]/.test(zipcode);
            if (!isValid){
           alert('Invalid ZipCode');
          document.getElementById("zipcode").value = "";
        }


    </script>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
            <?php include("include files/favicon.php"); ?>
        </head>
        <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
            <?php 
            include("include files/header.php");
            ?>
            <?php 
            include("include files/navigation.php");
            ?>
            <!--breadcrumb-->
            <div id='location'>
            <div id="BannerAndNavigatorHtmlBlock_StoreNavigator_pnNavigator" itemscope=""  itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb">
            <span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" class="btn btn-success">
            <a itemprop="item" href="/">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" itemprop="name">
            </span>
            </a>
            <span itemprop="position" content="1">
            </span>
            </span>
            </span>
            <span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem"class="btn btn-success">
            <span itemprop="name">Playing Card Quote</span><span itemprop="position" content="2"></span>
            </span>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!--Main Content-->
            <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="container">
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="well">
            <form action="thank-you.php" method="post" id="form1" onsubmit="MM_validateForm('quantity','','R','fname','','R','email','','NisEmail','telno','','RisNum','address','','R','city','','R','state','','R','country','','R','zipcode','','R');return document.MM_returnValue && jcap();">
            <fieldset>
            <legend>
        <h1>Fill Quote Form</h1>
    </legend>
    <div class="quote-form">
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6">Plastic Coated Paper :</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <select class="form-control" name="plastic_coated_paper" id="plastic_coated_paper" onchange="chgSelect('coatedpaper');">
                        <option selected value="0" id="selectpaper">Select Paper</option>
                        <option>Black Centered 330</option>
                        <option>Black Centered 320</option>
                        <option>Black Centered 315</option>
                        <option>Black Centered 305</option>
                        <option>Black Centered 300</option>
                        <option>Black Centered 280</option>
                        <option>White Centered 330</option>
                        <option>White Centered 320</option>
                        <option>White Centered 315</option>
                        <option>White Centered 305</option>
                        <option>White Centered 300</option>
                        <option>White Centered 280</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:center;">
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                          <center>OR</center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6">100% Pure Plastic : </label>
                <h2>Your Contact Information :</h2>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                      <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div>
                   <input  name="fname" id= "id" type="text" onSubmit="" tabindex="2" required="required">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Last  Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div>
            <label>
        <input name="lname" id="input1" type="text" tabindex="2" required="required">
                </label>
            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Email Id</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                 <div>
                <label>
                 <input name="email" type="email" tabindex="2" required="required">
                </label>
                 </div>
                 </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5">(Please type in a correct email address , as the quotes will be forwarded there)</div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Telephone Number</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div>
                <label>
                <input  name="telno" id="telno" type="text" tabindex="2" required="required">
                </label>
                 </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">( Do not enter space)
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Mobile Number</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div>
                <label>
               <input  name="mobileno" id="mobileno" type="text" tabindex="2" required="required">
                </label>
                 </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6">&nbsp;<i>*</i> Company Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
               <div>
                <label>
            <input type="text" name="txtCompanyName" id="txtCompanyName" required="required" onclick="TestCompanyName('txtCompanyName')">
         </label>
            </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input id="address" class="address" type="text"   name="address" 
                onchange="IsValidAddress(this.form.address.value)" required="required" >     
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Zip Code :</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
       <input id="zipcode" class="zipcode" type="text"  name="zipcode" onchange="IsValidZipCode(this.form.zipcode.value)" required="required" >
    <br />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div> 
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> City</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="city" type="text" id="city" required="required" value="">   
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> State</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="state" type="text" id="state" value="" required ="required">     
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Country</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="country" type="text" id="country" value="" required="required">    
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6">&nbsp;Fax</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input class="form-control" name="fax" type="text" id="fax" value="" required ="required">    
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-6"><i>*</i> Captcha</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
        <body>
    <form name="review" ACTION="newpg.html" METHOD="POST" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
    <font color="#DD0000">Enter Code ></font> <span id="txtCaptchaDiv" style="background-color:#A51D22;color:#FFF;padding:5px"></span>
    <input type="hidden" id="txtCaptcha" />
    <input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput" size="15" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkform(theform){
    var why = "";

    if(theform.txtInput.value == ""){
    why += "- Security code should not be empty.\n";
    }
    if(theform.txtInput.value != ""){
    if(ValidCaptcha(theform.txtInput.value) == false){
    why += "- Security code did not match.\n";
    }
    }
    if(why != ""){
    alert(why);
    return false;
    }
    }

    //Generates the captcha function
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
    var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
    var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';
    var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9)+ '';

    var code = a + b + c + d + e;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;

    // Validate the Entered input aganist the generated security code function
    function ValidCaptcha(){
    var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
    var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
    if (str1 == str2){
    return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
    }

    // Remove the spaces from the entered and generated code
    function removeSpaces(string){
    return string.split(' ').join('');
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
            <center>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn1" name="submit" id="send">
            </center>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <!---footer---><?php include("include files/footer.php");?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I am not able to provide validation for captcha using validation? My function is not displaying message for me if security code did not match or security code should not be empty.

What is the problem in the program? Why is not validating my captcha properly? I tried it many times but not able to validate my captcha code

What is the error in the page for captcha validation? What is the correct validation for captcha ?

Comment: Why have you tagged this Java?  There's no Java here.

Comment: sorry dude it is Javascript code

Comment: Yup.  And now that someone's put the correct language on it, it's possible you'll get an answer.

Comment: This is probably too broad. I have removed lots of hidden text from your question about "what code do I need" and "how do I do validation", which sounds like you want someone to do your work for you. Given that you seem to be asking for `THE DAMN REGULAR EXPRESSION` I think you need to do some more work on this, and come back to us when you have a more specific question. Remember that Stack Overflow is not a factory for free work.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does not have any issues. It does what it is supposed to do, generate a code and validate that the input matches it before allowing the form to be submitted.

However, if you are really interested in preventing bots from submitting the form, then this code is not going to help you at all. You generate the code on the client and save it in your input. A bot would read that input and provide the captcha with no issues at all.

EDIT: suggestion for recaptcha

I would suggest that you integrate your application with an established recaptcha provider, as is for example recaptcha. Please note that the validation of the captcha input should be performed **in your server**
You can find further details for [recaptcha here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/).

Comment: so dude JChrist provide me the bot links as early as possible

Answer (score 0):

The code is working as you might expect. Please review the fiddle I had to made no change at all.
https://jsfiddle.net/43m63ezf/

**HTML**

```
<label>Captcha</label>
<form name="review" ACTION="palying-cards-quote.php" METHOD="POST" onsubmit="return checkform(this);">
  <font color="#DD0000">Enter Code </font> <span id="txtCaptchaDiv" style="background-color:#A51D22;color:#FFF;padding:5px"></span>
  <input type="hidden" id="txtCaptcha" />
  <input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput" size="15" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function checkform(theform) {
  var why = "";

  if (theform.txtInput.value == "") {
    why += "- Security code should not be empty.\n";
  }
  if (theform.txtInput.value != "") {
    if (ValidCaptcha(theform.txtInput.value) == false) {
      why += "- Security code did not match.\n";
    }
  }
  if (why != "") {
    alert(why);
    return false;
  }
}

//Generates the captcha function
var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';
var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 9) + '';

var code = a + b + c + d + e;
document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code;
document.getElementById("txtCaptchaDiv").innerHTML = code;

// Validate the Entered input aganist the generated security code function
function ValidCaptcha() {
  var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
  var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
  if (str1 == str2) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

// Remove the spaces from the entered and generated code
function removeSpaces(string) {
  return string.split(' ').join('');
}
```